# Is it possible to have a one line if with more than one result?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have a method with an if statement that i want to get onto one line if possible. However one part of the condition has two results - `pay later` and a `redirect_to`. Is is possible to have this on one line?
It doesnt like the syntax when i do it. (I know this will be very long if on one line)

```html
    def invoice
      if @invoice.reason?
        pay_later
        redirect_to admin_invoices_path, notice: t(".success_delay")
      else
        redirect_to new_admin_invoice_payment_path(@invoice)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The code you have is perfectly logical

Comment: Can you? Sure you can, with some parentheses and semicolons. Should you? Absolutely not.

Comment: Consider `redirect_to new_... unless  @invoice.reason?; pay_later; redirect_to admin_...`. The first statement (here) is sometimes call a *guard clause*.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you ca try

```
def invoice
  @invoice.reason? ? pay_later && redirect_to(admin_invoices_path, notice: t(".success_delay")) : redirect_to(new_admin_invoice_payment_path(@invoice))
end
```

But it's not cool at all. And it works only if `pay_later` does not return a falsey value

Comment: You assume `pay_later` returns a truthy value.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I specified!

Comment: Let's see what the OP says :)

Comment: Try now @SergioTulentsev :D

Comment: Yes, now better :)

Comment: BTW, it's really easy to change this code to not depend on `pay_later`'s return value. Then you wouldn't need that caveat.

Comment: How? Semicolon?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. @Ursus code works great.

Comment: The readability here is really, really low. The original code, while more verbose, leaves it abundantly clear what's going on. This is just a jumbled mess of confusion by comparison. It works, but at what cost? *Just because you can doesn't mean you should.*

Comment: I was just trying to answer the OP question. I even said that is not cool at all.

Comment: @Ursus: yep, semicolon and parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you probably don't want to.

```
def invoice
  (pay_later; return redirect_to admin_invoices_path, notice: t(".success_delay")) if @invoice.reason?
  redirect_to new_admin_invoice_payment_path(@invoice)
end
```

A common way to avoid placing your whole method body inside an `if..else` block is to use a guard clause:

```
def invoice
  return redirect_to new_admin_invoice_payment_path(@invoice) unless @invoice.reason?

  pay_later
  redirect_to admin_invoices_path, notice: t(".success_delay")
end
```